# How to show Knowledge article list History in Search Bar

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, knowledge, history-tracking, field-history

I have created list of Knowledge articles in articles management standard object. i need to show that articles list in search bar when i am searching for related questions/data that time i need to show that questions related list in automatically search bar below in visualforce page like attached screen shot

can any one suggest me on this...

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? You can get the list with a simple query. As for displaying it you'll need to implement javascript. For help with javascript you can visit stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose Knowledge tab instead of Article Management tab to get the same search functionality what you are looking for.

You don't need to create custom visualforce components for that.

Refer [Improve the Article Search Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_search_improve.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Please let me know how can i add exact that standard functionality in visualforce page (this is my requirement need to add search bar in visualforce page)

Comment: You dont need visualforce page, refer trailhead or salesforce documetation for implementing knowledge. Refer my blog post http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2018/05/retain-your-knowledge.html?m=1

Comment: sorry Santhanu, my requirement is need to show the drop down search box in visualforce page, so i need to get the knowledge articles values from page for end users to display in the site

Comment: this post might help you https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kAIRIA2